# error burning in nero

Tags: nero

I was trying to burn some videos on the dvd. It took about 7 minutes to burn it. But I got this error when the burning was about 100%. Will it have any effect on the video or the dvd. Why did I get this error?
[alt text http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6863746/pics/avatar.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6863746/pics/avatar.png)

Comment: What filesystem are you burning with? Joliet? UDF?

Comment: the default used by nero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your file system, the names might be too long. Try using directories (eg `h:\Avatar\Book1\Chapter 20 - The seige of the north 2` or simply `h:\Book1\Chapter 20 - The seige of the north 2`)

Answer (score 0):

The filenames are too long to be burned. You should either make the filenames much shorter before you burn the files to disc or use UDF mode. A good program that is an alternative to nero is CDburnerXP. It will suggest solutions when you get problems like these, and switch settings around for you.